# Git Pull Request of feature branch based on other feature branch showing all commits

Tags: git, github

I've got a situation in which I've branched one feature (`feat-a`) from `develop`. Did some work, then sent a PR back into `develop`.

After that, waiting for the PR to be approved, I branched again off `develop` for `feat-b`. I did a commit and then realized that a fix I had done in `feat-a` is required for `feat-b` to move on.

So, at this point, the situation is this:

```
develop  A → B       
             |\
feat-a       | C → D
              \  
feat-b         E → F
```

Now, I thought of rebasing `feat-b` onto `feat-a` to get my fixes from `feat-a`. Then I submitted a second PR for `feat-b` onto `develop`.

Now the situation looks like this:

```
develop  A → B       
              \
feat-a         C → D
                    \
feat-b               E → F
```

For this reason, my `feat-b` PR includes commits `C` and `D`. I am assuming that, at this point, there is nothing I can do to avoid it. What is the best practice in this case? Writing a note on the PR that `feat-b` depends on `feat-a`?

However, there is something more I don't get: once `feat-a` PR gets approved and now `C` and `D` are part of `develop`, why does my `feat-b` PR still show `C` and `D` as part of the PR if they were approved? Anything I can do about this?

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/ to learn more about merge, merge base, and pull request.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm giving it a read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I thought of rebasing feat-b onto feat-a

Yes, well, that was a mistake. One feature branch should not grow out of another. They need to be independent. Otherwise what if `featA` is rejected? Your `featB` is basically sneaking it in anyway. Plus as you can see it messes up the history.

Now that you've done that, you need to rebase `featB` `E` and `F` back onto `develop` before submitting the PR. This moves the merge base so that the PR is correctly constructed from just `E` and `F`.

```
git rebase --onto develop featA featB
```

Comment: But `feat-b` PR was already submitted. Would that mean that, after `feat-a` PR is merged into `develop`, I would then rebase again `feat-b` onto `develop` and then force push? Also, since you mentioned that was a mistake, what would have been the proper way to do this?

Comment: Actually at this point you might be better off closing the messed up PR, starting a replacement branch from develop, and cherry picking E and F to it.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/325856. That answer says your rebase was ok as long as you rebase back as I'm saying.

Comment: I see what you mean, and that makes sense completely. Also what you say about not branching a feature from another and sneaking things back in. But given a situation in which an important fix comes from `feat-a`, how would you suggest to proceed next time? Of course the best way would be to wait for `feat-a` to be approved, but excluding that, how would you do it?

Comment: You have said it. If featB cannot proceed without stuff in featA then pick up another ticket and wait until featA is merged

Comment: Alright, thank you. It seems that there is no other way besides that, then. :) Thanks for the time.

Comment: Or else (we do this sometimes) close featA PR and just resubmit it as featB which now is the only one and has all the commits from both and satisfies two tickets.

Answer (score 1):

This is a side note, that logically should be a comment, but requires formatting.

You've drawn your branches the right way around, which means you have drawn them the wrong way around.  That's because Git works backwards, not forwards.  You therefore need to draw your branches the wrong way around, so that they will be the right way around.

That is, instead of:

```
develop  A → B       
             |\
feat-a       | C → D
              \  
feat-b         E → F
```

you should use:

```
A <-B   <-- develop
    |\
    | C <-D   <-- feat-a
     \
      E <-F   <-- feat-b
```

The name `feat-b` selects commit `F`.  Commit `F` points *backwards*, to earlier commit `E`.  Commit `E` does not, and cannot, point forwards to commit `F` because all parts of any commit are frozen for all time the moment the commit is created.

Commits `A-B` are on all three branches, because commits `E` and `C` both point backwards to commit `B`.  The commits that are "on" a branch are those that are *reachable from* what Git calls the *tip commit*.  The branch name automatically updates, as you make new commits, so that the name always selects (points to) the tip commit.  Commands like `git reset`, that can force a branch name to point to any arbitrary existing commit, do not affect the actual set of commits in the repository, but do affect which commits are findable via which branch-name.

Remember that Git works backwards, and many other things will begin to make sense, that did not before.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks! Visualizing things like that surely helps. But in this case, it doesn't answer my question/problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: See the first sentence above: "This is a side note, that should be a comment..."

Comment: Yep, I was just making sure I wasn't missing anything. Thanks for the explanation! :)